# What is the default height of UIBarButtonItem because it can't be 20?

Tags: ios

I search "for default height uibarbuttonitem" in google and found nothing.

Where in the documentation it is mentioned?

This is for portrait.

Some says the size is 20. I tried 20 and there is no way the size is 20. It should be much higher.

The purpose of this question is so I can create a REGULAR button that emulates a UIBarButtonItem.

Note: most people say it's 20.

I set the height as 20 and it's clearly seen that the regular button is much smaller than UIBarButtonItem.

[image]

Should I include a screenshot?

As you see, the bottom campaign is 20 points height. And that's much shorter than the upper UIBarButton. So the upper UIBarButton can't be 20 points. How much?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1590170/how-big-should-a-uibarbuttonitem-image-be

Comment: Why does it matter? Can't you just use something like `button.frame.size.height`?

Comment: This link will help you http://www.idev101.com/code/User_Interface/sizes.html

Comment: It's NOT DUplicate. It's not 20. Here I give screenshot

Answer (score 4):

```
   The default height of UIBarButton is 20 points
```

Comment: No it's not. It's bigger. I saw it. It's bigger than 20 by 20

Comment: Look again on the pics, it's NOT 20

Comment: @SeptiadiAgus- See my edited ans plz

Answer (score 2):

About 20×20 points, according to the [Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconsImages/IconsImages.html)