# Image in UI Navigation Bar

Tags: ios, uiimage, uibarbuttonitem

I'm trying to put an image onto the UI Navigation Bar and facing a couple issues with tint. The image is a 40*40 with transparency (png).

The image looks like this in xcode:

[image: logo]

When I place in as the image of a UI Bar Button Item it appears as this:

[image: navigation bar]

Notice how the color's have changed. The default color of the app is brown and hence the default tint is shining through.

How do I get the original colors of the image to show?

Thanks

edit:

aspect ratio issue:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Taken from the apple documentation:

*UIImageView includes the tintColor property. When the image view contains a template image—that is, an image that specifies the UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate rendering mode—tintColor is applied to the image.*

So you need to set the rendering mode of your image to: `UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal`

```
UIImage *originalImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"navBarImage.png"];
originalImage = [originalImage imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
//Then apply the image to the navigation bar
```

If you are developing for an iOS app which seems to be the case then I suggest leaving your image the way it shows atm as it looks much better having it flat than it does with your origianl image. This is just my opinion, I feel that it its clearer and clean.

Comment: Thanks! This solved the tintColor problem. But now the aspect ratio of the image is lost. I'll update the question with a picture. I'm using a square 40px image as per [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1590170/how-big-should-a-uibarbuttonitem-image-be[link]

Comment: Dude, have you tried to atleast research on the aspect ratio bit? and how to set the frame of an imageView? Because its quite an easy fix

Comment: But i'm not using an imageView. I was taking a short cut but just using a bar button item and then putting the image on that :)

Thanks though - I solved the problem using: http://www.appgroup.co.uk/adding-a-uibarbuttonitem-with-a-custom-image/

Also flattened my image - thanks for the reccomendation

Answer (score 2):

Swift:

```
let customImageBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(UIImage(named: "someImage.png").withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleClick))
```

A `22pt x 22pt` icon size works better.

i.e. a `66px x 66px` image @3x for iPhone Plus phones etc.