# tool bar uibarbutton image is not showning in iOS

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitoolbar

I  am trying to show custom image for UibarButtonItem in Toolbar.

but it shows like **"Circle" instead of custom image**
my imagesize of 60 x 60

Following is the screenshot of it

[image]

my Image Properties
[image]

**How to solve this?**

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: whats you image extension?

Comment: Show the relevant code. And don't forget that by default, the image needs to be an alpha mask.

Comment: @ShantiK, Thanks for reply..it is in .png format

Comment: @rmaddy, you can see image properties above. I just add image from nib file

Comment: I don't think you understand what an alpha-mask is. Read the docs about the `image` property of the `UIBarButtonItem initWithImage:style:target:action:` method.

Comment: This link may helpful for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1590170/how-big-should-a-uibarbuttonitem-image-be

Comment: @Bhumeshwerkatre, still not working