# backBarButtonItem image in iOS 8

Tags: ios, swift

Assume that I have a `ViewControllerA` that points to `ViewControllerB`, I can set the title of Back button in `ViewControllerB` via this in `ViewControllerA`:

```
navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .Plain, target: nil, action: nil)  //set title to blank
navigationController?.pushViewController(destinationVC, animated: true)
```

However, how can I replace the image? I tried this but I still only see the default "Back" image, instead of a custom image:

```
navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "back-toolbar"), style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: nil, action: nil)
```

[image]

I want to use this image:

[image]

After reading many other SO posts, I don't want to implement a `leftButtonItem` for each destination view like `ViewControllerB` and have to manage the back Action and swipe left gesture.

I also can't set the image in AppDelegate because I use one image for some views and another image for other views.

**UPDATE**:

Per @rounak's tip, I was able to set the backBarButton, but the position seems wrong. Any way to adjust it?

[image]

Comment: Please explain the actual results you're seeing and how these differ from the actual results you want.  "it doesn't work" is not a sufficient description of your problem.  What's "not working" about it?  Does it crash?  Does it compile?  Are their warnings or errors?  Does it run fine and simply display the standard look versus whatever your image is?  Does it launch missiles?

Comment: Sorry, I added a screenshot.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can just set the `backIndicatorImage`:

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorImage = UIImage(named: "back")
navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = UIImage(named: "back")
```

This will apply the indicator image only for that navigation controller, rather than all navigation controllers in your app. You can change this image inside your view controller in `viewWillAppear`/`viewWillDisappear` for view controllers that need a different back image.

Comment: Thanks @rounak, that worked. Is there a way to adjust the image size and position? The size and position seems a little off.  PS. Good tip on resetting it on `viewWillDisappear`.

Comment: @Dean iOS typically does a good job at positioning the back button, but if you find that unsatisfactory, you can try adding a little margin to the image to move it to the side you want.

Comment: What's the size of image I should create? iOS doesn't seem to be resizing the image.

Comment: @Dean HIG recommends that bar button images be 22x22 http://stackoverflow.com/a/1591139/424406

Comment: What about removing the back button text?

Answer (score 3):

There's no need to set the `leftButtonItem` for each view controller. You can replace the image via the appearance property selectors of `UINavigationBar` which will set the default back indicator image for the whole app.

Here's an example in Objective-C, i'm sure you can easily find it's Swift equivalent:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackIndicatorImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back-toolbar.png"]];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackIndicatorTransitionMaskImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back-toolbar.png"]];
```

Comment: Hi Artal, unfortunately I can't do that. I have some views that use one image for back button and other views that use another image.

Comment: @Dean I see. But, you can still use this method multiple times and switch the image to the correct one before showing certain view controllers, and change it back when they are dismissed.

Comment: If you do just that, the back button text will still be there.