# UIImage shows an empty square instead of image

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

I try to show a `png` image on my navigation panel. I do as following:

```
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"];
UIBarButtonItem *myButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:img style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(myAction)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = @[myButton];
```

The `img` isn't `nil`, however `myButton` is shows as a white square. The size of this square is the same as the size of my `image`, but the image isn't shown, just a white square. I have a `@2x` version of my image for retina and I selected my project as a target for both these images.

What can be wrong?

Comment: Have you sized it accordingly [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1591139/1565335)?

Comment: Read the document, "Toolbars", particularly the section entitled, "Bar Button Item Icons". This will explain your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/BarIcons.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH21-SW1) for Toolbar and navigation bar icon (optional) :

Regardless of the icon’s visual style, create a toolbar or navigation bar icon in the following sizes :

About 22 x 22 pixels (standard resolution)

About 44 x 44 pixels (2x)

About 66 x 66 pixels (3x)

**Code :**

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
UIImage *newImage = [image imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
UIBarButtonItem *myButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:newImage style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(myAction)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = @[myButton];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"1"];**//1.png previously**

UIBarButtonItem *myButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:img style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(myAction)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = @[myButton];
```

**Just remove .png simply give the image name and it will work.**

Comment: If you using image assets then and then you can do like this. without image assets you have to write the extension.