# iOS: How to set the proper image scale for a bar button item

Tags: ios, xcode, uibarbuttonitem

I'm trying to add my own image as a bar button item, but I don't know how to get the image to scale properly. Apple's Human Interface guidelines recommends that my image be 44x44 px, but when I use a 44x44 px image, it is too large for the toolbar, as you can see:

[image: Example]

When I use a smaller version of the image, it looks pixellated on the Retina display. What am I supposed to do here?

Comment: Use 22*22 image.Take 44*44 as your 2x and 66*66 as your 3x.May be it will solve your problem.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "take 44*44 as my 2x"? Is there somewhere in XCode where I specify what scale to use?

Comment: she just want to say ,when you setting image, set button size to {22,22}.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How big should a UIBarButtonItem image be?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1590170/how-big-should-a-uibarbuttonitem-image-be)

Comment: In images.xcassets, you can add image sizes for 1x, 2x, and 3x sizes. Your app will automatically use the correct size.

Comment: @goodcow That was it, thanks. Submit it as an answer if you'd like.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In images.xcassets, you can add the images as 1x, 2x and 3x. Xcode will use the appropriate image size depending on the device.

Answer (score 7):

You need to follow apple guidelines for designing you can find it from this link https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LayoutandAppearance.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH54-SW1

You can find the attached screenshot image for correct sizing for the UIBarButtonItem image size as par the apple guidelines you have to use 44X44 for ratina (@2x) and 22X22 for normal (@1x) for UIBarButtonItem[image]

Answer (score 1):

`width 22 pixels X height 22 pixels` -  ideal for left or right BarButtonItem.
You can resize any image to custom sizes using online tools,  one such I used is
http://www.picresize.com/