# Align app logo to left of the navigation bar

Tags: ios, swift

I want to put logo of my app as button on left of the navbar.

I tried to implement the same by calling configureNavbar() function in init of the veiw controller.
Definition of the function is as follows:

```
private func  configureNavbar(){
        var image = UIImage (named: "NetflixLogo")
        image = image?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: image, style: .plain, target:  self, action: nil)
    }
```

By this I am getting logo in middle of the navbar like this:

[image: logo in middle of navbar]

But by using:

```
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [
            UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(systemName: "person"), style: .done, target: self, action: nil),
            UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(systemName: "play.rectangle"), style: .done, target: self, action: nil),
        ]
```

I can see items at right of navbar.

[image: items at right of navbar]

Pls help how can I align app logo to the left?

This is what I am getting in debug hierarchy

[image: Debug Hierarchy View]

Comment: Try using an actual small square image instead of a wide rectangular image.

Comment: Can you try something like this?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48618571/10175156

Comment: @TejuAmirthi tried this but image got stretched in horizontal direction to all the width shown in debug hierarchy. And now icons on right are also not visible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In viewDidLoad set your custom view and add to navbar like a custom view:

```
    let leftNavBarImageView = UIImageView()
        leftNavBarImageView.image = UIImage(named: "yourImage")
        leftNavBarImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        leftNavBarImageView.backgroundColor = .white
        leftNavBarImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 4 // if you don't want corner radius comment this line
        leftNavBarImageView.clipsToBounds = true
        leftNavBarImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true // set image view width constraint
        leftNavBarImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true // set image view height constraint
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: leftNavBarImageView) // add left bar button custom view
```

This is the result:

[image]