# Resize UIBarButtonItems

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

How do i resize UIBarButtonItems? Here's how i setup nav bar button items for a webview

```
        navForwardButton = UIBarButtonItem.init(image: navRightImage, style: UIBarButtonItem.Style.plain, target: self, action: #selector(navigateForwardButtonClicked))
        navBackwardButton = UIBarButtonItem.init(image: navLeftImage, style: UIBarButtonItem.Style.plain, target: self, action: #selector(navigateBackwardButtonClicked))
        cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem.init(title: "Cancel", style: UIBarButtonItem.Style.plain, target: self, action: #selector(cancelButtonClicked))
```

which looks like 
[image]
How can i make these button items smaller

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1590170/how-big-should-a-uibarbuttonitem-image-be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add like this also.

```
    func addRightButton(){

    let viewFN = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 180,40))
        viewFN.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
    let button1 = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(0,8, 40, 20))
    button1.setImage(UIImage(named: "notification"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    button1.setTitle("one", forState: .Normal)

    button1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.didTapOnRightButton), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

    let button2 = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(40, 8, 60, 20))
    button2.setImage(UIImage(named: "notification"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    button2.setTitle("tow", forState: .Normal)
    let button3 = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(80, 8, 60, 20))
     button3.setImage(UIImage(named: "notification"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    button3.setTitle("three", forState: .Normal)

    button3.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.didTapOnRightButton), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

    viewFN.addSubview(button1)
    viewFN.addSubview(button2)
    viewFN.addSubview(button3)


    let rightBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: viewFN)
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightBarButton

 }
```

Comment: Hey that works, thanks a lot. But this seems like a lot of work for something that should be automatic